# GET component on sharepoint list in react MGT

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-toolkit

How can GET component be used with sharepoint list item. I did use list item graph api endpoint. However, not sure how to use template against response in React

I see some example in non react ( mgt-get) solution but i couldnt port in React.

Any samples?

I do get response as well. Unable to figure out how to render this response.  Endpoint is, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Does the `sharepoint list item` have a specific graph api?

Comment: Yes. Updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help as a sample? Let me know if you need more specific examples.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mgt-react-login-sfsfpx?file=src/App.js

Comment: I guess I relied little too much on the intellisense . I did not see any property exposed from datacontext and assumed I am doing something wrong. Your example is fine. Thank you !!